MFC: rect provided to EM_REQUESTRESIZE cuts off text?
As I understood it, setting up ENM_REQUESTRESIZE would issue EN_REQUESTRESIZE  to change the height (but not the width) per this article.
However, I found the call was changing the height and width.   I only want the height to change.  In my example the width was shorter than I want the rich text box so I just use the existing width, but the issue is the height was not high enough and cuts off the text.

Here's what I did:
void CDialogX::OnEnRequestResize( NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult )
{
   _ASSERT( pNMHDR->code == EN_REQUESTRESIZE );

   CRect rect;
   m_ctlRichEdit.GetWindowRect(rect);
   ScreenToClient(rect);

   CDebugPrint::DebugPrint(_T("existing size %i %i %i %i\n"), rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
   
   REQRESIZE* prr = (REQRESIZE*)pNMHDR;
   m_ctlRichEdit.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rect.Width(), prr->rc.bottom - prr->rc.top, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOMOVE);

   CDebugPrint::DebugPrint(_T("requested size %i %i %i %i\n"), prr->rc.left, prr->rc.top, prr->rc.right, prr->rc.bottom);

  // get new size
  m_ctlRichEdit.GetWindowRect(rect);
  ScreenToClient(rect);

  CDebugPrint::DebugPrint(_T("new size %i %i %i %i\n"), rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
  
  // ...
  
  *pResult=0;
}

The debug output was:
existing size 60 57 329 58
requested size 60 57 241 70
new size 60 57 329 70

What am I doing wrong?
More Details:
If it's multi-line text, the last line is cutoff the same as the picture.  If I calculate the border via GetWindowRect() vs GetClientRect() it's zero, if I calculate the internal border via GetRect() (EM_GETRECT) and GetClientRect() it's 1.

I don't see anything in the official docs that say only the height is resized and not the width.  It makes sense that if the RichEdit's width is smaller than its text then EN_REQUESTRESIZE may request a larger width. The parent window can choose whether it wants to accomodate that or not.

@RemyLebeau the bigger issue is the height cutoff - maybe I have to calc the border.

I can reproduce this problem with a plain (non-MFC) Win32 RichEdit.

The text is getting cut off because you are not resizing the RichEdit large enough. Near as I can tell, the requested rectangle is for the client area of the RichEdit, but you are interpreting the rectangle as being for the window as a whole.
Try taking into account the spacing between the RichEdit's text and borders.  You can use both CWnd::GetWindowRect() and CWnd::GetClientRect() and then add the difference to the requested height, eg:
CRect rect;
m_ctlRichEdit.GetWindowRect(rect);

CRect crect;
m_ctlRichEdit.GetClientRect(crect);

REQRESIZE* prr = (REQRESIZE*)pNMHDR;
m_ctlRichEdit.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rect.Width(), (prr->rc.bottom - prr->rc.top) + (rect.Height() - crect.Height()), SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOMOVE);

When I do this, the text is not cut off anymore.


I just added more information - I get zero as the border size in that case.

When I do it, the spacing between the text and border is 2px on each side, so expanding the requested height by 4px works

It may be the visual styles of BCGControlBar Pro - I get a border of zero doing it that way - if I hard code 4 or 6 I get the correct result.

AH-HA - I kept messing around with it - I setup the initial size of the control to be only 1 pixels high (then later tried 2 in case that was an issue) that would ensure the resize request is issued  .. so then I just tried setting it to 18, and now it has a border width ..
